# mod_rewrite Clean URL rewriting

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm trying to write clean url's for my website. I'm a rookie at this so forgive me. My .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ something.php?query=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ something.php?query=$1
```

The first rule seems to work. For example `website.com/good-looking-query-string` does in fact rewrite to `website.com/something.php?query=ugly+looking+query+string`
The second rule is where I'm having a problem. I can't get that trailing slash to work. For example `website.com/good-looking-query-string/` appears to pull up the page but without any CSS rules applied. I noticed all the links end up appended to the query string also. For example the link back to index.php ends up like `website.com/good-looking-query-string/index.php`
I need to get that trailing slash to work. What in the world am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine two line in one line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ something.php?query=$1
```

In this case `/` will be optional

Comment: That will just put the slash in the `query` parameter. This is a client side issue.

Comment: You are not wrong nor right, the reason that happens is that he put the `CSS` files with relative address, so `src="style.css"` need to get the files from current folder, but since he is not giving the correct address (the rewrite is not working correctly) the current page address is changed to (/good-looking-query-string/).
So your comment is correct for fixing the problem of css, which will fix the relative addressing but his problem is also is with rewrite rule which I tried to expain

Comment: The page will still be at the child directory level though so all requests with relative paths will still be one too high. See the last part `website.com/good-looking-query-string/index.php` it should be `website.com/index.php`

Comment: Isn't the `something.php` on the main level? Or I understood it wrong. (Also I updated my answer

Comment: Got it! It was a relative path thing. I just added `<base href="website.com">` in my header and all is well. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is client side, you are using relative paths but you need to be using `Root-relative` paths.  A URL of:

```
website.com/good-looking-query-string
```

loads from the root. A url of:

```
website.com/good-looking-query-string/
```

loads from the `good-looking-query-string` directory.

So instead of `href="style.css"` you should have "href="/style.css"`and the index issue should be`href="/index.php"`instead of`href="index.php"`.

As noted in the earlier comment your regex could be simplified by adding a `?` on the trailing slash to make it option. That is not your issue though, just simplifies the rules.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ something.php?query=$1
```